# What is an initial consistent estimator and how do I find one?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization, gradient-descent, consistency, two-step-estimation

When maximizing a likelihood function $L(\psi)$, the gradient-based optimization procedure is generally
$$ \tag{5.1}
\hat{\psi}_{r+1} = \hat{\psi}_{r} + \left| I^{*}(\hat{\psi}_{r}) \right|^{-1} D \log L(\hat{\psi}_{r})
$$
where $D \log L(\hat{\psi}_{r})$ is the gradient and $I^{*}(\hat{\psi}_{r})$ is some approximation to the information matrix (for instance the Hessian in Newton-Raphson), evaluated at $\psi = \hat{\psi}_{r}$ In [Harvey (1990)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Econometric_Analysis_of_Time_Series/yKQN62Itmg0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA141), it says that a *single* iteration of this procedure gives a consistent and asymptotically efficient estimator, if $\hat{\psi}_{0}$ was the "***initial*** consistent estimator" of $\psi$.

Here's the (abridged and highlighted) relevant quote from [Harvey (1990), pp. 140-42](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Econometric_Analysis_of_Time_Series/yKQN62Itmg0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA141).

> (5.1) defines a fairly general iterative scheme in which a variety of expressions may be used for $I^{*}(\psi)$. The essential point is that under standard regularity conditions, $I^{*}(\psi)$ is asymptotically equivalent to the information matrix [...]. A two-step estimator is constructed by evaluating the r.h.s. of (5.1) at a *consistent* estimator of $\psi$. **In other words only one iteration is carried out, with $\hat{\psi}$ being the initial consistent estimator of $\psi^{*}$ the two-step estimator.** The attraction of this procedure is that the two-step estimator has the same asymptotic distribution as the ML estimator. [...] Estimators formed by one iteration of (5.1) are sometimes referred to as *linearised maximum likelihood*. [...] Iterating (5.1) further will usually result in an estimate which is closer to the ML solution, although this certainly cannot be guaranteed. However, **iterating beyond the first round will not change the asymptotic distribution of the estimator even if continuing the process eventually produces the ML estimator.**

The book then continues with a proof for the case of a single parameter, but says "a general proof may be constructed along similar lines."

But as a practical matter, how would this work? When and how would one have a starting value $\hat{\psi}_{0}$ that just so happens to be consistent? Or is this just a theoretical result with no practical implications?

EDIT: I dug a little deeper, and found this [1975 article by Bickel](https://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.1975.10479884). He talks about estimating equations more generally. Here's the relevant quote, where I adjusted the notation to Harvey's above:

> $$ \tag{1.1}
> \sum_{i=1}^{n} \phi (X_{i} - \hat{\psi}) = 0
> $$
> where $X_{i} = \psi + E_{1}, \ldots, X_{n} = \psi +E_{n}$ and $E_{1}, \ldots, E_{n}$ are unknown independent, identically distributed errors which have a distribution $F$ which is symmetric about 0. If $F$ has a density $f$ which is smooth and if $f$ is known, then maximum likelihood estimates if they exist satisfy (1.1) with $\phi = -f'/f$. [...] It has, however, been observed by Fisher, Neyman and others that if $F$ is known and $\phi = -f'/f$, the estimate obtained by **starting with a $\sqrt{n}$ consistent estimate $\hat{\psi}_{0}$ and performing one Gauss-Newton iteration** of (1.1) is asymptotically efficient even when the MLE is not and is equivalent to it when it is.

My question remains: where would this initial consistent estimate $\hat{\psi}_{0}$ come from?

Comment: Unable to view link. Says I have reached max number of allowed page views. Is it possible to share the relevant details in a public domain?

Comment: I added a relevant quote of the material, which should be considered fair use. I also changed the notation to match the book.